# Win2d blur doesn't always work in c++

Tags: c#, visual-c++, windows-phone-8.1, win2d

I'm trying my hand at writing WP apps in c++ and have a strange problem with blurring .png image. It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. When it doesn't work it appears as if image was invisible. Just to be sure I implemented same thing in C# and it works perfectly. This is my C# code

```
private async void blurDefaultAvatar() {
    try {
        var storageFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Assets\\menu_user.png");
        using(var imgStream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync()) {
            using(var stream = await getBlurredImageStreamWithStream(imgStream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Png)) {
                var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.SetSource(stream);
                blurredAvatar.Source = bitmap;
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Avatar load fail: {0}", e.Message);
    }
}

private async Task<IRandomAccessStream> getBlurredImageStreamWithStream(IRandomAccessStream stream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat format) {
    try {
        var device = new CanvasDevice();
        var bitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(device, stream);
        var renderer = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, bitmap.SizeInPixels.Width, bitmap.SizeInPixels.Height, bitmap.Dpi);

        using(var ds = renderer.CreateDrawingSession()) {
            var blur = new GaussianBlurEffect();
            blur.BlurAmount = 30.0f;
            blur.Source = bitmap;
            ds.DrawImage(blur);
        }

        var imgStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await renderer.SaveAsync(imgStream, format);

        return imgStream;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Avatar blur fail: {0}", e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and more or less (I hope) equivalent in c++

```
void MainPage::blurDefaultAvatar(){
  concurrency::create_task(Package::Current->InstalledLocation->GetFileAsync(L"Assets\\menu_user.png")).then([](concurrency::task<StorageFile^> t){
      try{
          auto storageFile = t.get();
          return concurrency::create_task(storageFile->OpenReadAsync());
      } catch(Exception^ e){
          std::wstringstream wss;
          wss<<"\nAvatar not found: '"<<e->Message->Data()<<"'\n";
          OutputDebugString(wss.str().c_str());
          return concurrency::create_task(concurrency::create_async([]()->IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType^{ return nullptr; }));
      }
  }, concurrency::task_continuation_context::use_current()).then([this](concurrency::task<IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType^> t){
      try{
          auto imgStream = t.get();
          concurrency::create_task(getBlurredImageStreamWithStream(imgStream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat::Png)).then([this](IRandomAccessStream^ stream){
              if(stream!=nullptr && stream->Size>0){
                  auto bitmap = ref new BitmapImage();
                  bitmap->SetSource(stream);
                  blurredAvatar->Source = bitmap;
              }
          });
       } catch(Exception^ e){
           std::wstringstream wss;
           wss<<"\nAvatar failed to read: '"<<e->Message->Data()<<"'\n";
           OutputDebugString(wss.str().c_str());
       }
   });
}

IAsyncOperation<IRandomAccessStream^>^ MainPage::getBlurredImageStreamWithStream(IRandomAccessStream^ stream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat format){
    return concurrency::create_async([stream, format]() -> IRandomAccessStream^{
        auto imgStream = ref new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        auto device = ref new CanvasDevice();
        return concurrency::create_task(CanvasBitmap::LoadAsync(device, stream)).then([stream, device, format, imgStream](concurrency::task<CanvasBitmap^> t){
            try {
                auto bitmap = t.get();
                auto renderer = ref new CanvasRenderTarget(device, bitmap->SizeInPixels.Width, bitmap->SizeInPixels.Height, bitmap->Dpi);
                auto ds = renderer->CreateDrawingSession();
                auto blur = ref new GaussianBlurEffect();
                blur->BlurAmount = 30.0f;
                blur->Source = bitmap;
                ds->DrawImage(blur);
                return concurrency::create_task(renderer->SaveAsync(imgStream, format));
            } catch(Exception^ e){
                std::wstringstream wss;
                wss<<"\nBitmap load fail: '"<<e->Message->Data()<<"'\n";
                OutputDebugString(wss.str().c_str());
                return concurrency::create_task(concurrency::create_async([]()->void{}));
            }
        }, concurrency::task_continuation_context::use_current()).then([imgStream](concurrency::task<void> t){
            try{
                t.get();
                return imgStream;
            } catch(Exception^ e){
                std::wstringstream wss;
                wss<<"\nStream save fail: '"<<e->Message->Data()<<"'\n";
                OutputDebugString(wss.str().c_str());
                return (InMemoryRandomAccessStream^)nullptr;
            }
        }).get();
    });
}
```

Methods are called with a press of a button. Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Close()/Dispose() the drawing session.  So in the C# version you have:

```
using(var ds = renderer.CreateDrawingSession()) {
    ...
    ds.DrawImage(blur);
}
```

Going out of the using's scope calls Close() on the drawing session.  In C++/CX  you call Close() with "delete ds".  So:

```
auto ds = renderer->CreateDrawingSession();
auto blur = ref new GaussianBlurEffect();
blur->BlurAmount = 30.0f;
blur->Source = bitmap;
ds->DrawImage(blur);
delete ds; // <<<<<---- add this
return concurrency::create_task(renderer->SaveAsync(imgStream, format));
```

This page has some more information about 'delete' and IDisposable.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh699870.aspx

The reason that you're seeing this sometimes work and sometimes not work is because when the ds goes out of scope it is also closed.  Sometimes this happens before the SaveAsync call has grabbed the D2D lock, and sometimes it happens after.  The net result here is that SaveAsync either saves the contents of the rendertarget before the blur has been drawn to it or it saves the contents after the blur has been drawn.

Comment: Great! I missed this. Thank you very much.